# Regex matching one word but not matching another

Tags: javascript, regex

What is wrong in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/RPdx4/

```
 function getMatches(data,city){
             var matchArr = [];
             var pattern = new RegExp("\\b("+ city +")","gi");
        for (var i in data){        
                 var searchStr = data[i].searchstr;
                 if(pattern.test(searchStr)){
                    matchArr.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return matchArr;
        }
```

I am able to match the first address object and and the last address object but i am not able to match the second one.But the second one also has the same word. Any idea why?

Comment: Fix your jsfiddle link, remove the extra `/1/`

Comment: Remove the "g" from the pattern, the reason is [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks it worked. You are a Life saver. I am totally unaware of that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.indexOf()`

```
 function getMatches(data,city){
        var matchArr = [];
        for (var i in data){        
                 var searchStr = data[i].searchstr;
                 var index = searchStr.indexOf(city);
                if(index!==-1) {
                    matchArr.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return matchArr;
        }

var arr = getMatches(x,'Dar es');
alert("arr: " + arr.length);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RPdx4/4/

---

OK, Regex just

`var pattern = RegExp('\\b' + city + '\\b')`

or

`var pattern = RegExp("\\b("+ city +")")`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RPdx4/5/

Comment: Yeah i know that. But i wanted to do with Regex.